# nginx stream file to connect to upstream service when proxy_bind is used

Tags: nginx, openvpn

I am trying to use nginx as a TCP proxy to OpenVPN on port 443.
nginx will forward connection to openvpn to port 1194.

I am able to configure this to work with openvpn without `proxy_bind $remote_addr:$remote_port transparent;` The setup works perfectly. Except that openvpn will not get the original client's IP Address. That is why I tried to use `proxy_bind`.

Note: For those who may think that I could simply point openvpn to port 443, my answer to you is that I am also running SSL HTTP server on nginx and I personally think that using `port-share` feature available with openvpn will cause more performance trouble than doing it this way as well as port-share provide no `X-Forwarded-Host` feature

Network Constraints: Connections from network to VPN server can only bet served on 443/TCP which clash with current HTTPS setup. Thus using nginx to receive TCP connection and pass it on to openVPN.

nginx: `nginx/1.13.1`
OS: `Ubuntu 16.04`

The nginx error simply saids

```
2017/06/10 16:00:55 [error] 2777#2777: *288 connect() failed (110: Connection timed out) while connecting to upstream, client: <REAL-CLIENT-IP>, server: <SERV-IP>:443, upstream: "127.0.0.1:1194", bytes from/to client:0/0, bytes from/to upstream:0/0
```

And here is `nginx.conf`
The below configuration is at the top level.

```
stream {
    upstream vpn_tcp {
        server localhost:1194;
    } 

    server { 
        listen <REAL-CLIENT-IP>:443 so_keepalive=on;
        proxy_connect_timeout 300s;
        proxy_timeout 300s;

        # If I commented out the below line, nginx would pass on TCP connections to the service with no problem except IP address that OpenVPN sees would be the server's IP not the Client
         proxy_bind $remote_addr:$remote_port transparent;
        #real_ip_header $realip_remote_addr:$realip_remote_port;
        #proxy_bind $remote_addr transparent;
        #proxy_bind $remote_addr;

        proxy_pass vpn_tcp;
    }
}
```

Comment: You really, really don't want to use TCP for VPN. Doing so will cause very poor performance on anything but a *perfect* network circuit.

Comment: I understand the drawback and that I should have use UDP instead, but that's not really really related to my problem that I am facing. Thank for suggesting anyway.

Comment: ServerFault is about doing things right. Even if it's ancillary to your question, if we see someone doing something wrong, we mention it. If you want a reliable VPN service, you must not use TCP. Period.

Comment: Additionally, since you know you should be using UDP, why are you even bothering trying to fix this? Just switch to UDP.

Comment: I am VPNing out from a restrictive network in order to access my server. By restrictive, Everything is blocked excluding 443/TCP

Comment: Why you try to use `nginx` it could be easily solved by `iptables`.

Comment: @AlexanderT I have HTTPS running on the very same server. I planned to use static IP/sub domain for VPN and Hostname for the HTTPS web server